# React and TS scoping/setState warnings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I've got a fairly simple react/redux app ([full repo](https://github.com/japhar81/redux_todo)). I basically have a simple web form with a pair of onChange handlers. Both are throwing the same warning;

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted
>   or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an
>   unmounted component.

The component itself is trivial - I've pasted the code below. I've used the TS anonymous ()=>{} syntax to get around scoping of `this`.

For some reason, when I log `this` in `componentDidMount`, it shows up with `_reactInternalInstance=ReactCompositeComponentWrapper`. The `this` logged in the onChange handler doesn't have that property.

Equally odd, `__proto__` of `this` in `componentDidMount` is `Login` (as expected), but in the callback handler, it's `ReactComponent`.

Both of these lead me to believe it is in fact a scoping issue, but I can't for the life of me see where I'm going wrong. Has anyone seen this before?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {FormControl, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {IAppState} from '../store/IAppState';
import AuthActions from '../actions/AuthActions';

interface ILoginProps {
}
interface ILoginState {
    username: string;
    password: string;
}

export class Login extends React.Component<ILoginProps, ILoginState> {
    static propTypes = {};
    state = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('mounted');
        console.log(this);
    }

    usernameChange = (event: any): void => {
        console.log(this);
        this.setState({
            username: event.target.value,
            password: this.state.password
        });
    }

    passwordChange = (event: any): void => {
        this.setState({
            username: this.state.username,
            password: event.target.value
        });
    }

    login = (event: any): void => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('login');
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <p>
                LOGIN
                <FormControl
                    type='text'
                    value={this.state.username}
                    placeholder='username'
                    onChange={this.usernameChange}
                />
                <FormControl
                    type='text'
                    value={this.state.password}
                    placeholder='password'
                    onChange={this.passwordChange}
                />
                <Button bsStyle='primary' onClick={this.login}>+</Button>
            </p>
        );
    }
}

export function mapStateToProps(state: IAppState) {
    return {};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, AuthActions)(Login);
```

Comment: Does TypeScript actually support defining class methods as arrow functions?  "Normal" class methods in ES6 aren't auto-bound to the instance.  The stage 2 Class Properties syntax lets you define methods as arrow functions which are then auto-bound, but I don't know how TS handles things.

Comment: It handles them like stage 2, they're auto-bound.

Comment: I'm seeing some differences between the sample posted here, and the code in the repo.  Looking at the repo version, you definitely shouldn't be trying to bind up `render()`.  React ensures that all lifecycle methods are called with the proper `this`.  Beyond that, I'm not exactly sure what's going on.